# Array filtering does not change the array in Crystal

Tags: arrays, filtering, crystal-lang

I got a Array of strings where i want to make a statement if something is true filter away this string in my array.

**The code**

```rb
module CrystalTest
    files = ["path/to/file1.ext", "path/to/file2.ext", "path/to/file3.ext"]

    files.reject do |file|
        reject = true
        reject
    end

    print files
end
```

I expect the result to be Array `files.size => 0` in this case becuase i set reject true to each iterration. But i keep getting `files => true`

**edit:** added the fule code snippet.

Comment: But? Please provide a more full fledged example. Extrapolating from what you've shown, it works: https://carc.in/#/r/6vne

Comment: That is the full code, there are not more magic to it, when I run print files after this code it returns true instead og  empty array? files is just an array of stings like so:

["path/to/file.ext", "path/to/file.ext", "path/to/file.ext"]

Comment: @JonneHaß I've added the full file now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array#reject` returns a **new**, filtered array. This means you either need to reassign your `files` variable like so:

```
files = files.reject do |file|
```

Or use `Array#reject!`, which modifies the array in place, like so:

```
files.reject! do |file|
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess i was missing the ! in my code, im just a very novice ruby dev only done few for fun projects. Comming form Javascript so trying to learn syntax and patterns as i go Thank you for the answer it works!